# Highchart reflow is not working when using bootstrap tabbing for multiple charts using class

Tags: php, jquery, highcharts, tabs

I have multiple highcharts in one page.

see below code

```
 <script  src="js/election/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script  type="text/javascript"  src="js/election/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
 <script src="/h-chart/js/highcharts.js"></script>
 <script src="<?= base_url() ?>election/h-chart/js/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

I have two tabs. both tab have multiple highcharts. I am creating highchrts using foreach loop

```
<div id="starbethak" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3 class="dist-chart-title">Star Bethaks</h3>
    <?php
    $old_area = '';
    foreach ($star_bethak as $key1 => $star) {
        $name = explode('$', $key1);
        ?>
        <div class="chart-stacked">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="chat-info">
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(function () {
                $(document).ready(function () {

                    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                        chart: {
                            renderTo: 'container_star_<?= $name[0] ?>',
                            type: 'column'
                        },
                        colors: ['#FE7A00', '#57A21E', '#0064B1', '#96D5D2'],
                        plotOptions: {
                            column: {animation: {animation: false}},
                            bar: {
                                dataLabels: {
                                    enabled: true
                                },
                                pointPadding: 0.2,
                                borderWidth: 0
                            }
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: ''
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            gridLineWidth: 1,
                            tickInterval: 5,
                            categories: ['']
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            min: 0,
                            //                                            max: 20,
                            title: {
                                text: ''
                            },
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            formatter: function () {
                                return '' + this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + ' seats';
                            }
                        },
                        legend: {
                            useHTML: true
                        },
                        credits: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        exporting: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        series: [
                        <?php
                        $votes = array();
                        foreach ($star as $s) {
                            echo '{name:"' . $s->first_name . '",data:[' . $s->cand_votes . ']},';
                            $votes[$s->party_id] = $s->cand_votes;
                        }
                        ?>
                        ],
                        events: {
                            render: function (event) {
                                chart.redraw();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    //chart.redraw();
                });
               });
                    </script>
                                                           <div class="district-name"><?= $name[1] ?></div>
                </div>
                <div id="container_star_<?= $name[0] ?>" class="district-detail-result" style="max-width: 228px ; height: 260px; margin: 0 auto; clear: both;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

This tab two code. My first tab charts are all good. it doesn't have any issue. but when i am clicking on tab two my highcart design is not rendering properly. When i do inspect element it automatically sets properly.

I have searched and applied all way but not working.

I tried  using tab shown method but it gives me error like

> TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function. I have already attached highchart js. I can not getting what is actual problem.

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) { // on tab selection event
                var target = $(e.target).attr("href"); 

                if (target == '#starbethak') {
                    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#starbethak"]').tab('show');
                }
                $(".district-detail-result").each(function () { 
                    var chart = $(this).highcharts(); 
                    chart.reflow(); 
                });
            });
```

How to resize multiple highcharts using class? I have referred [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14954624/highcharts-does-not-resize-charts-inside-tabs) , but its not working.

This one is image before inspect element.
[image]
This is after inspect element.
[image]

Is there any issue my graph creation loop? Help Please.

Comment: By default Highcharts adjust it's size to the size of it's container. When the container is resized the chart needs to be reflown (https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#reflow) manually. Have you tried to use this function? **Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/mcdgofLh/